# Input type date. How to don't let 2 inputs of this type be the same

Tags: html, angular, validation, input

Basically i have 2 inputs that are both of type date. I don't want the user to able to submit the form if the check-in has a date after the check-out. For example if the check in is 11/02/19 and the check out is 10/02/19 then the user won't be able to submit the form. I don't want to give the user this option.

```html
<div id="dataCheckIn">
                                <h3>Check-in:</h3>
                                <input type="date" formControlName="checkInReserva" required>
                            </div>
                            <div id="dataCheckOut">
                                <h3>Check-out:</h3>
                                <input type="date" formControlName="checkOutReserva" required>
                            </div>
```

Comment: I would recommend adding a validator to the form group. That will give you the ability to compare any field to any other field in the group and set error messages accordingly.

Comment: How do I add the validator then? You mean a onInvalid function basically? @Brandon

Comment: @fernidui No, the FormGroup has a property, `validators`, to which you can add your custom validator. There is also an `asyncValidators` property if you need to connect to services to do validation.

Comment: Yeah that's it @jae.phoenix